# Compressing revision history based on current text

Tags: java, perl, node.js, compression

I am aware that gzip and other compression routines operate using byte-level deduplication. I was just wondering if there was a standard routine for writing like a second half gzip.

Specifically, for revision history. Current text would be in plain, and previous revisions would be in a compressed blob. Is there a way to set the current plain as starter text in a compression, without actually including the current text in the compression result. Thus both compressed and starter text would be used together to decompress.

I am interested in Java, Perl, Node.JS, and I suppose C/C++, since there are ways to call the compiled file using one of the aforementioned languages. In this case, I would build the C files on UNIX.

Does such a routine exist, is there one significant / available more than one language?

Comment: Also study how git does delta compression.

Answer (score 1):

Using Zip, you could include 2 separate files, and not compress one of them

I know Java has facilities for doing stuff with zip files

Comment: Would the second file use the first file as reference for the compression? example, one totally random file (meaning it cannot be compressed) is the "current revision", then a previous revision is to be written to the history. If the previous revision is almost entirely identical, it should take only minimal space, because it is deduplicated based on the current revision which is "not compressed". My first impression is that your solution would separate the current and previous revisions, without actually allowing the previous to be "based on" the current.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to set the current plain as starter text in a
>   compression, without actually including the current text in the
>   compression result.

There are two ways.  You can use [zlib](http://zlib.net/)'s `deflateSetDictionary()` to provide up to 32K of history to the compressor which it would use to compress what is fed to it.  The 32K is not included in the compressed data, and the decompressor would require that that 32K be available to it somehow for successful decompression.

Perhaps more effective, especially for text longer than 32K, would be to use Unix `diff` to generate the difference between the revision and the current text, and compress the result of `diff`.  You could do successive `diff`'s for multiple revisions, and compress all of it.

Comment: Is diff going to be enough to allow me to recreate a previous revision?

Comment: If it's text, then diff/patch should recover the original.  You'll need to be careful with the options, since it is possible to tell diff to ignore certain kinds of changes, e.g. changes only in white space.

Comment: If you want something truly lossless regardless of whether the input is text or binary, you'll need to stick with the first approach, using the compression dictionary.